# React renders before updating component

Tags: reactjs, state, render

I want my react component to update the state before it renders. Right now I have a set of questions that is gotten from an API. So depending on the url, the questions change. When I leave the component and come back in (with the new state) It first shows the old state for a second or two before showing the new state.

Comment: Execute your code to update state in the constructor of the component.

Comment: Could you give a [mcve]?

Comment: @Himanshu Pant I dont understand what you mean by that

Comment: @jonrsharpe the code is rather large

Comment: That's why it says *minimal*, you need to cut it down.

Comment: You wouldnt understand it there is a lot of redux stuff

Comment: Please have a look at the lifecycle of components. [link](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html) and or [link](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html), what you might be looking for is the componentWillUnmount method.

Comment: Thank you so much but @Adam has given me the componentWillUnmount method

Comment: I understand Redux, too. But is the Redux **relevant to the problem**? That's the point of creating the example, to isolate where the issue actually is. You might even fix it yourself in doing so.

Comment: I have fixed it already. Thanks @jonrsharpe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `componentWillUnmount` lifecycle method to cleanup your state data

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentwillunmount

Comment: Thank you for that @Adam

Comment: I think here you should create an initial state and serve that when the component mounts. When unmount’ing you should update state to initial state.

Comment: @NSJCorps while I can’t disagree Adams answer. However I would say you should never need the state containing the questions. But rather the name (unique question id) and the value of the question answer from `event.target` Good luck 